Nuxt 3 pages:extend route same name route file
When I want to add an additional route from nuxt.config.ts, the problem is that the route name is taken from the file file.
come with me :
test.vue :
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  name: "test",
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
  </div>
</template>


in nuxt.config.ts :
  hooks : {
    "pages:extend"(pages) {
      pages.push({
        name: `testExtend`,
        path: `/testExtend`,
        file:  "~/pages/test.vue",
      });
    }
  }

This route is supposed to be named testExtend, but in fact its name is the same as test.vue in definePageMeta
Also in dev tools in the Pages section in Route Path:

page /test has become unavailable
It is not even visible in devtools in pages

expectation? What do you mean?

Personally, I believe the best way to duplicate a page is to make it into a component and use it in two separated pages, instead of using nuxt hook.
